# Reducing the number of points in quiverplot keep them equidistant

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using pyhton 2.7 with the matplotlib libary. There I am using quiver to plot a grid.

I have the following problem:
I am calculating a grid of points. each point is associated with a x,y distortion. For algebraic reasons the values come in form of a vector of dimension 2n instead of a matrix nXn. All in all i have 4 vectors which i am feeding into Quiver of Matplotlib:  position X, Y and distortion X_R Y_R (component distortion)

It plots really nicely but since I have 10201 points the plot is a black mess of arrows and requires excessive fine tuning of the arrow length scaling factor. I want to avoid that by reducing the number points I am plotting. 
Here the Issue:
when I reduce the number of points using only lets say every tenth point X_R[1::10] I loose the *symmetry* in the plot which *I NEED TO SHOW.*

Example:

I have n=5 so my grid is a 5X5 matrix. the vectors i feed have 25 entries: 
If I only allow for every third value to be shown I have the issue:

```
        2,-2 2,-1 2,0 2,1 2,2
        1,-2 1,-1 1,0 1,1 1,2
        more values...
```

which translates to the following vector:

```
        (2,-2; 2,-1; 2,0; 2,1; 2,2; 1,-2; 1,-1; 1,0; 1,1; 1,2;....)^T
           X          X         X     X          X         X
```

I want to plot all the values I marked with an X. If I take only every third value I plot:

```
        (2,-2; 2,-1; 2,0; 2,1; 2,2; 1,-2; 1,-1; 1,0; 1,1; 1,2;....)^T
           X          X         X           X          X
```

Loosing the symmetry of the plot.

**CODE**

```
        def plot(d, XY_p,Number):
"""Plot displays Matplotlib moduls quiverplot. Enter scaling factor.
Use Matplotlib features to save, zoom etc.
Feed Zemax data array d, transformed points XY_p and variable Number"""

redo=0

while redo == 0:
    xy_p=XY_p
    Dummy_array=d
    NUMBER=Number

    b=XY_p.size #size of XY_p
    X_p=xy_p[0]
    Y_p=xy_p[1]

    n=2
    while n<b:
        X_p0=xy_p[n]
        Y_p0=xy_p[n+1]
        X_p=np.append(X_p,X_p0)
        Y_p=np.append(Y_p,Y_p0)
        n=n+2


    i=0
    DeltaX=[]
    DeltaY=[]    

    while i<NUMBER:

        x_r=float(Dummy_array[i][7])
        y_r=float(Dummy_array[i][8])


        x_p=(X_p[i])
        y_p=(Y_p[i])




        DeltaX0=np.array((x_p-x_r)*1000/PLATE_SCALE )
        DeltaY0=np.array((y_p-y_r)*1000/PLATE_SCALE )

        DeltaX=np.append(DeltaX,DeltaX0)
        DeltaY=np.append(DeltaY,DeltaY0)

        i=i+1

    scaler=input("Input your scale factor for vector length e.g. 1...100, the larger the scale the shorter the arrows: ") 


    Q = plt.quiver(X_p[0::], Y_p[0::], DeltaX[0::], DeltaY[0::], scale_units='width', scale=scaler)
    #qk=plt.quiverkey(Q,1.0,0.92,2,r'$ [mas] $')
    print("To plot again close plot window")
    plt.show()

    redo=input("To replot enter 0: ")
```

OK I can't show you the plots as they are company interna but here is a sketch:

I am plotting a symmetric grid with values [1,2,3].

```
3  2  1  2  3
3  2  1  2  3 
3  2  1  2  3
3  2  1  2  3 
3  2  1  2  3
```

Maybe it helps to imagine 1,2,3 as different colours of red to yellow (e.g. red sides yellow middel)

As you can see this has y axis symmetriy. What happens if I only take every third value:

```
3  x  x  2  x 
x  2  x  x  3 
x  x  1  x  x  
3  x  x  2  x 
x  2  x  x  3
```

no more y axis symmetry! I need away of adressing the values in a manner that keeps the y axis symmetry:

```
 3  x  1  x  3
 3  x  1  x  3
 3  x  1  x  3
 3  x  1  x  3 
 3  x  1  x  3
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example? It's hard to guess what you mean with "losing symmetry" without seeing the plot.

Comment: Sorry i can't post any of the plots and mimiking face zeemax files is a huge pain in the ass.  but maybe this can help understand:

My plot has lets say a y axis symmerty. thus the arrow at position (-1,2) and (1,2) will be facing each other.  If you take a look at what happens If i only take every third value:
It can happen that instead of attaching arrows to (-a,b) and (a,b) with symmetric distortion (arrows facing i.e. in the same direction) it will plot (-a,b) and (a,b+1). as there is no correlation between those points it will appear as if not symmetric.

Comment: So what I want to do is an indexing in the vector that isn't equidistant.

If the values were in matrix (grid) representation I want to address 
every second value in a row. But that is **not the same** as addressing every second in the vector.

Comment: We can't guess what is in your mind. You need to provide the information to understand your problem... you are the one trying to get help here.

Comment: I made some additional Comments, that I hope clarify what I mean.